# Python Syntax "checks = len(g[max(g, key=lambda key: len(g[key]))])"

Tags: python, syntax

I am Relatively new to python, and I am not sure what exactly this statement does. And I'm also unsure of the token `lambda` here.

**What exactly does this statement mean/do?**

```
checks = len(g[max(g, key=lambda key: len(g[key]))])
```

Comment: ```g``` looks like a dictionary, can you share that

Comment: @Sujay This is the code I have written to find ```g```

Comment: @Sujay ```g = {i: [] for i in range(len(l))}
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(i, len(l)):
            if i != j and loop(l[i], l[j]):
                g[i].append(j)
                g[j].append(i)```

Comment: That's a rather cumbersome way of getting the maximum length of the dict values. You can instead map the dict values to the `len` function and get the maximum of the mapped lengths with `max(map(len, g.values()))`.

Comment: I suggest you to read an introductory Python tutorial first, instead of posting a new question on Stack Overflow for every line of Python code you saw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checks = len(g[max(g, key=lambda key: len(g[key]))])
```

Let's start from the inner statement.
'max' is going to return the maximum value, in this case using the defined lambda function as key indicator. The lambda function returns the length of the dictionary value, having that provided key.
Afterwards you use that maximum value inside the g[] brackets, which is going to return the dictionary value with the returned maximum value as key.

Since you wanted the keyword lambda clarified: Lambda calls are anonymous functions, which you can for example quickly use without defining a def statement. They are particularly useful for list comprehensions, or other quick operations, like this one.

In the end you pass that value to the len function, which is going to return an int with the length of the value.